# States/functionals on crossed product C*-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, crossed-products

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra, $\alpha$ a strongly continuous automorphic action by a locally compact group $G$ on $A$, and consider the crossed product $A\rtimes_\alpha G$. I am looking for references where I can read up on what is known about relations between the state spaces of $A$ and $A\rtimes_\alpha G$. (The case $G={\mathbb R}^n$ would be sufficient for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the special case, where $A$ is the group vNa algebra of a type 1 group $H$, and $\alpha$ acts on $H$ via automorphism, then the extremal states  on $A \rtimes_\alpha G$ correspond roughly to irreducible representations of $H \rtimes_\alpha G$ (assume that for instance that $H$ is compact), and these can be computed via the Mackey machine (Look at Mackey's paper "Group extensions of locally compact groups"). I would guess that Mark Rieffel has extended this to more general settings, but I am not very knowledgable in this area.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; but I would actually be more interested in this without choosing $A$ in a special way. Is anything general known then?

Comment: Here is something about the commutative situation $A=C_0(X)$: folk.uio.no/sergeyn/papers/traces.pdf. I am sorry, I do not have any more information than google can give, or what I have mentioned. So there is probably more than this. 